# Compound conditions in SQL Server 2008 stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Can you please let me know if stored procedure allow to handle compound condition as below:

```
if(
    ( (select Count(*) from dbo.Membership where EmailID=@emailID) >0) 
                                  || 
    ((select Count(*) from dbo.Allocation where ResourceEmail=@emailID)>0))
)
```

Comment: When I try to compile the stored procedure, I get the error message.

Comment: **Please** let us know **exactly what** error message you're getting.....

Comment: Looks like your parenthesis are not balanced to me.  You have an extra `)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `OR` instead of `||`

More optimal if just checking for existence, I'd use EXISTS instead of COUNT as it will stop when it first the first existence, instead of counting them all...

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Membership WHERE EmailId = @emailID)
    OR EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Allocation where ResourceEmail=@emailID)
    BEGIN
       -- emailID exists in one of the 2 tables
    END
```